# How to customize variable "next" in Django login form?

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django login, we see a variable called "next" to redirect to the next page after login. How to control this variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In settings.py define [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `django.contrib.auth.views.redirect_to_login` you can pass in the url as next which is a required argument.